# Problems loading data in to Analysis Services Model

Tags: powerbi, ssas, data-modeling, powerquery

I’m building an model in Azure Analysis Services. The model should contain only data for the last 3 months and is processed every day.

I have a separate dimension for date that has a relation with a fact table using a datekey. I’m using a power query to only load the last 3 months in the date dimension. In the power query to load the fact table I used Table.nestedjoin to only load the rows that have a value in the date table.

When I do this, the processing of the model takes forever. After some troubleshooting I saw that the query Analysis Services is using to retrieve data from the SQL database retrieves all rows. So, Am I correct saying AS load all data before it merge the rows? Is there a way to change this? Or is there a better way to a chief my solution?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Joins are super slow in Power Query. You should avoid them if you can do it in the datasource or use normal relationships in the data model.
Also, you can setup the date dimension in DAX and dynamically populate it to contain only dates present in the FACT table.
As for the load of all the data, it could be because the data is fetched as is, and only then power query applies the transformations (the join).

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the query in the Power Query Editor / Advenced Editor to add a where clause direclty in the query

[image]

[image]